# How to get around storage quota limits in a progressive web app

Tags: file-upload, upload, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My question is essentially how can I get around the storage quota limits enforced on a PWA? A little background...
I am hoping to create an offline-ready line-of-business progressive web app that would ideally push about 2GB of images and video resources onto my user's phones or tablets - well beyond the current storage quota for caches and Indexed DB.  What I'd like to be able to do is have my users (we all work at the same company) do a 1 time download of a zip file or directory and have the user's store that on their phone/tablet's file system in a well known directory.  As the online version of the app treats these files as URL's, the fetch api would seem ideal since I could serve from online if connected or the local serviceworker managed cache if not online. But the qouta limits have me stumped. None of the files are larger than 15MB, but there's no way to know which files are needed before a user goes offline. Can I use something like an HTML input type=file tag to load files into the cache at runtime and then treat them as URL's? Of course I would remove other files to make room.   But since these files wouldn't be coming from "the origin" with its secure https address (a PWA requirement I think) , but rather a local file system, I'm not sure this will work.  If it is workable, would my users be forced to browse to the files manually?

Answer (score 1):

If its an option, you can have a native Android service to do the caching part to avoid space constraint and then serve the data from native code to PWA using websockets/secure web sockets.

No PWA solution possible for now. File API has limitation as its sand-boxed.

Comment: Interesting idea - I'm strictly an HTML / Javascript developer so I'd need to find an app on the play stores I guess that could act as a secure file server and provide content on request.  Because of the PWA restriction that a URL must come from your domain, 
 It probably couldn't serve that content as an addressable URL though could it?

Comment: You can fetch the cross domain URLs. but wont be able to cache it though.